# Font Book: Smart Collections: User fonts only

Tags: font-book

Is it possible to filter out all but user-installed fonts
or all but system-installed fonts in smart collections?

For example, filter down to all user-installed monospace fonts.

Answer (score 1):

When I open Font Book, there is a sideboard on the left side of the window. It is shown below.

[image]

You can see on the left that User is highlighted. Selecting User will display only the User installed fonts.

Comment: Thank you; however, I am unable to further filter from this point without the use of a smart collection.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a Smart Collection (e.g. sorted by language, name, kind, or style) will always include all such fonts on the computer.